# visual studio not showing package right and application is missing

Tags: visual-studio, package, icons

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqwPo.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7XzOC.png)

hi i hope you can help,
as you can see i opend a package with the shirt icon but when it is opend it shows the gift icon and no application.

what can i do to fix this

thanks everyone

i wanted to open a package and it doest open right because it doesnt show the right icon and content